# inplace replacement works for object but not string dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

Replace method on object dtype yields different result than on string dtype.  I was expecting same result.  I'm running Pandas 1.1.0 on Python 3.8.5.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c'],'b':['d','','']},dtype='object')
b = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c'],'b':['d','','']},dtype='string')

print(a)
a.replace(r'^\s*$',pd.NA,regex=True,inplace=True)
print(a)

print(b)
b.replace(r'^\s*$',pd.NA,regex=True,inplace=True)
print(b)

   a  b
0  a  d
1  b   
2  c   
   a     b
0  a     d
1  b  <NA>
2  c  <NA>

   a  b
0  a  d
1  b   
2  c   
   a  b
0  a  d
1  b   
2  c
```

Comment: I am getting the same output for both of them. The spaces are replaced by NA. Yeah one corrrection, change `'string'` in `b = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','c'],'b':['d','','']},dtype='string')` to `'str'`. So, what was the output that you were getting?

Comment: That is weird, I am getting replaced values for the same snippet. Did you change dtype to `str`?

Comment: dtype='str' creates object dtype, while dtype='string' creates stringDtype, which is what I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

This is a confirmed bug.  See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35977